# Linq Expressions on Repository Interface

Tags: asp.net, repository, repository-pattern

I'm currently trying to find the right architecture for my Solution, but I have one doubt, is it wrong to create a Repository Interface containing methods with lambda expression arguments?

For example:

```
IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(Func<TEntity, bool> where);
```

Using Entity Framework i can easily implement this on my concrete repository:

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(Func<TEntity, bool> where)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(where).ToList();
    }
```

But our main objective by separating data access on another layer is to provide an abstraction on the data access and facilitate future data hosting migrations.

Is it possible to implement this repository method on another Data access technology? For example sql queries directly to database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but it is not very simple. What you need to do is to implement an `IQueryable<T>` LINQ *Provider*.

This [walkthrough from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb546158(v=vs.110).aspx) explains how to do it. You may need to change the signature of your method to take `IExpression<Func<TEntity, bool>>`, and returning `IQueryable<TEntity>`:

```
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(IExpression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
{
    return DbSet.Where(where).ToList();
}
```